# Why are none of modern aligning methods working for this markup?

Tags: html, css

## I am currently working on a webpage ...

```css
.content {
  background-color: #BAC9FF;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
}
.title {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="title">
      我的 DICTIONARY
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" width="60" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I have tried applying several techniques such as "`margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`" and also tried changing it to "block" and forcing my navbar elements into place by using `display:absolute`. However, to no avail, I was not able to. Is there any suggestion to transform my page from the current ...

[image: Current]

### To, my mock-up (As you can see, the logo is centered):

[image: Mock-up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another way which works seamlessly is centering with `left` and `transform: translateX()` attributes:

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Additionally, if you want to also center the element vertically, do the same with `top` and `translateY()`

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Advantages:

- There is no need to know the width or height of your element.
- The element will always be centered according to its parent

Disadvantages:

- Not supported in IE8 and below, and all versions of Opera Mini.

A few notes:

- The parent of the element being centered needs to have a non-static `position` attribute (e.g. `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`).
- There is no need to have `display: block` for divs unless you overwrite it in another rule. [This attribute is initially set to `block` for divs.](https://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/)
- It is generally not a good idea to use vh for sizing certain elements - for example, your navbar. It is going to look very different on various aspect ratios - think about 16:9 for laptop and 9:16 for mobile devices (portrait). Use em, rem, or px instead to preserve aspect on any screen sizes.

Another solution is using flexbox (as mentioned in @GCyrillus' answer), but this will also remove the compatibility with IE9. Large number of bugs are also reported for IE10 and 11.

See [CanIUse page for flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Below is a snippet with your the changed code.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #BAC9FF;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.title {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="title">
      我的 DICTIONARY
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" width="60" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much, however, can you please tell me why the `.logo class` must be `absolute`? And what does `left:50%` and `right:50%` do? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Muymuy1, the `left` and `right` attributes only work on a relatively-positioned item - that is, a `position` attribute set to anything different than `static`, which is the initial one. Setting it to `absolute` will make the item not occupy any space and can be positioned anywhere on the screen according to its **first relative parent**. Thus, for example, setting `left: 50%` and `absolute` position, your element will be 50% far from the left of its parent. You can learn more about it in [this page](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/). Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex and eventually rethink structure:

```css
header,
header div,
header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;/* push things appart from edge to edge */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header div {
  width: calc(50% + 60px - 1em);/* 50% + width of image - padding */
}
header nav {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
header> * > * {
  margin: auto 1em;/* vertical align(same as align-items: center + margin-left&right : 1em */
}
header {/* makup to see its center */
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40&text=logo" />
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

You might also use display:table to support old browsers (such as IE8 ):

```css
header,
header div,
header nav {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header {
  display:table; 
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
header div ,
header nav {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:justify;
}
header > :after,
header > :before{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:99%;
  
}
header > nav {
  text-align:right;
  padding-left:40px;
}
header> * > * {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
header {/* makup to see its center */
  padding:0  1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-right:-30px;
}
nav a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:30%;
  margin:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40&text=logo" />
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

both technic allows to `vertical-align` content *(wich seemed to be your issue)* and easily spray them inside
notice the `text-align:justify` + pseudo to mimic the `justify-content:space-between` from `flex`.

Comment: This is a neat solution but using both `calc()` and `flexbox` is not supported in IE9 and below. Also, using the star selector is not a very good approach in terms of performance. See my answer for centering with `transform`.

Comment: @Siavas, an answer should not be paste without some understanding, the `*` deserve to be a class or a specific tag here indeed. ....  Just added a `display:table` approach to support IE8 in the case it was needed :). also a negative margin + padding to get rid of the calc() to center the known size logo image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `display:inline-block` attributes from the logo update your css to

```
.content {
        background-color: #BAC9FF;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .navbar {
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
    }

    .title {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 3vh; 
        padding-left: 1vw;
        margin-top: 3vh;
    }

    .logo {
       margin-left:50%;
       margin-right:50%;
    }
```

You may still want to tweak the title class to control the width of the title div element to prevent the div from spanning the entire width of the page but this change will center the logo.

Comment: Removing the `display: inline-block` attribute makes the first element occupy the entire width, so the second element wraps down in the parent.

Comment: divs by default are block level elements so you don't need that attribute applied. Block level elements by default inherit the width of the parent element so you need to either adjust the width of each element or change your html structure. display:block treats the element as position:absolute which takes the element out of the page flow which is why it is positioned to the left.

Comment: I think there is a confusion regarding the `position` and `display` attributes. By default, as you say, divs are set to `display: block`, which makes them occupy the full width of the parent. Having `display: inline-block` makes the element occupy its necessary space, according to its children and sizing attributes (`width`, `height`, `flex`, etc.). There is no direct relationship between `position: absolute` and `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure the html changing the `div` elements to `span`

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <span class="title">
      我的 DICTIONARY
    </span>
    <span class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" width="60" height="50">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

then in the css

```
.content {
  background-color: #BAC9FF;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.title {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3vh;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

[here is a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8gybcmg/)